# draw an svg arc between lat longs

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, svg, google-maps-markers

The following draws a curve:

```
var curvedLine = {
    path: 'M 50,-150 A 100,100 0 0 100 -3,0',
    fillColor: 'transparent',
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    scale: 1,
    strokeColor: 'gold',
    strokeOpacity: 0.6,
    strokeWeight: 7
};

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: newLoc,
    icon: curvedLine,
    map: map
});
```

In the `curvedLine`, after `A`, can I give a location coordinates on the  map?
Because when the map is zoomed out, `curvedLine` size remains same. I want it to scale along with the map zoom.

Comment: You could find a rule to adapt the scale compared to the zoom level, but that sounds quite difficult and a bit weird. Instead you could try to use a Polyline.

Comment: Icons are not intended to draw anything **between** locations.

Comment: @MrUpsidown, I think I did exactly that. But the thing is only the start and end coordinates are given. So I have written a function. Check in the answer.

Comment: @Dr.Molle: I understood that. I am implementing using polyline. kindly review the answer I am posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a function. Please review it.

```
function drawCurvedLine(startLatLng, endLatLng, offset, right, left, lineColor) {
    var midLoc = getMidPoint(startLatLng, endLatLng);// Get the mid point of the start and end LatLngs
    var midLoc1 = getMidPoint(startLatLng, midLoc);// Get the mid point of the start LatLng and mid LatLng
    var midLoc2 = getMidPoint(midLoc, endLatLng);// Get the mid point of the mid LatLng and end LatLng
    var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(startLatLng, endLatLng);// Compute the heading of the start and end LatLngs

    // Change the heading based on right or left value 
    var headingOffset;
    if (right == 1 && left == 0) {
        headingOffset = 90;
    }
    else if (right == 0 && left == 1) {
        headingOffset = -90;
    }

    var offsetLoc = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(midLoc, offset / 1.5, heading + headingOffset);// Get the offset location of the mid point of start and end LatLngs
    var offsetLoc1 = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(midLoc1, offset / 2, heading + headingOffset);// Get the offset location of the mid point of midLoc and start LatLng    
    var offsetLoc2 = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(midLoc2, offset / 2, heading + headingOffset);// Get the offset location of the mid point of midLoc and start LatLng

    // Draw poly line along above computed locations
    var curve = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [startLatLng, offsetLoc1, offsetLoc, offsetLoc2, endLatLng],
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: lineColor,
        strokeOpacity: 0.6,
        strokeWeight: 7
    });

    curve.setMap(map);

    // Add an arrow to the end of the curved line
    var arrow = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: newLoc,
        map: map,
        icon: {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_OPEN_ARROW,
            scale: 4,
            strokeColor: lineColor,
            strokeOpacity: 1,
            strokeWeight: 5.0,
            fillColor: 'transparent',
            fillOpacity: 0.6,
            rotation: google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(offsetLoc2, endLatLng)
        },
    });

}
```